# UITabBarController difference in ios5 and ios6

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6

I Have written a following code for creating UITabBarController

```
{
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    STPC_AgendaController *agendaController = [[STPC_AgendaController alloc]initWithNibName:@"STPC_AgendaController" bundle:nil];

    STPC_Sponserer *Sponserer = [[STPC_Sponserer alloc]initWithNibName:@"STPC_Sponserer" bundle:nil];
    Sponserer.tabBarItem.title = @"Sponsors";
    STPC_AboutUsViewController  *aboutUs = [[STPC_AboutUsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"STPC_AboutUsViewController" bundle:nil];
aboutUs.tabBarItem.title = @"About us";

    UINavigationController *agendaNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                initWithRootViewController:agendaController];

    agendaNavigation.tabBarItem.title = @"Agenda";

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    [arr addObject:agendaNavigation];
    [arr addObject:Sponserer];
    [arr addObject:aboutUs];

    [self.tabController setViewControllers:arr animated:YES];

    [self resignFirstResponder];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tabController.view];
}
```

however it is acting differently in ios5:
 [image: ios5]

and ios6:
 [image: ios6]

PFA screenshots for ios5 and ios6. how to create a tabbar controller  so that it will look exactly same in ios5 and ios6?

any help appriciated.

Comment: Sorry, which picture is iOS 5 and which is iOS 6?

Comment: A quick tip for screenshots: you can press `CTRL`+`S` to save a screenshot from the iOS simulator on the Desktop.

Comment: the picture having white stripe after tabbar controller is ios5 and which normal is ios6